# How can I implement ImageJ's Non Local Means Denoising algorithm in Java code?

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

I'm trying to use [this java class](http://imagej.net/Non_Local_Means_Denoise) from ImageJ to denoise my image in java.

My attempts have lead me to this test class in conjunction with [these two classes (the github page linked to from ImageJ's website)](https://github.com/thorstenwagner/ij-nl-means/tree/master/src/main/java/de/biomedical_imaging/ij/nlMeansPlugin):

```
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.process.ByteProcessor;
import ij.process.ImageProcessor;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String directory = "C:\\Users\\Speedy Octopus\\Desktop\\Noise Reduction\\Before Denoising.JPG";
    BufferedImage image = ImageUtility.loadImage(directory);

    ImageProcessor ip = new ByteProcessor(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    String title = "New Image";
    ImagePlus imp = new ImagePlus(title, ip);

    NLMeansDenoising_ nlmd = new NLMeansDenoising_();
    nlmd.setup("final", imp);
    nlmd.run(ip);
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to get the nlmd.setup() done correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question.

The entire Test class looks like this now:

```
import ij.IJ;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.io.FileSaver;
import ij.plugin.PlugIn;


public class Test implements PlugIn {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test test = new Test();
    test.run("Denoise.ijm");

}

@Override
public void run(String arg0) {
    String directory = "C:\\Users\\Speedy Octopus\\Desktop\\10Cover Shots\\10.JPG";

    ImagePlus imp = IJ.openImage(directory);
    FileSaver fileSaver = new FileSaver(imp);

    System.setProperty("plugins.dir", "C:\\Users\\Speedy Octopus\\Downloads\\ij150-win-java8\\ImageJ\\plugins");
    IJ.run(imp, "Non-local Means Denoising", "sigma=5 smoothing_factor=1");
    fileSaver.saveAsJpeg("C:\\Users\\Speedy Octopus\\Desktop\\10Cover Shots\\10edited.JPG");
}
}
```